# Dúvida de lambda em um tipo

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Como eu faço uma lambda para trazer apenas registros que contem a palavra Traslado?
Por exemplo, nesse meu exemplo, existe 19 registros, mas 3 não são Traslados, logo deveria vir 16. Abaixo meu código e minha lambda errada.

```
OfferV2[] traslado = ((OfferV2[])SessaoUtil.Recuperar("MontaTraslado"));

                traslado = traslado.Where(x => x.).Contains("Traslado");
```

Comment: Em qual propriedade do objeto OfferV2 você espera que essa palavra apareça?

Comment: Seu exemplo nem compila.

Comment: Não compila porque é exatemente como eu disse, minha lambda está errada. O Propriedade ProductName

Comment: Se faço assim: traslado = traslado.Where(x => x.ProductName).Contains("Traslado"); dá erro na linha x.ProductName, dizendo não é possível conveter string to bool

Comment: Poderia  por o código da classe OfferV2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deveria ser algo do tipo:

```
var traslado = ((OfferV2[])SessaoUtil.Recuperar("MontaTraslado"))
    .Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains("Traslado"))
    .ToArray();
```